# How to declare method return value?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

Ok, i have this class Libray that uses another class named Book. 
I want to make a method that erase an object book in the array inventary, but i dont how to
declare the return value of the method, i want to return the object libray to use it in another class, where i will display all the books in it.
The num variable its given by the user in another class, its represents the number of the book to erase. The array inventary starts from 0 to 9.

```
public class Library {

 private Book[] inventary;
 private int     booksquantity;

 public Library eraseBook(int num){
    for(int i=0 ; i<booksquantity ; i++){
         if(i == num-1){
            for(int j = i ; j<booksquantity ; j++){
                inventary[j] = inventary[j+1];}
         }          
   }return ***;
 }  
}
```

//In the other class i would make something like this to use this method eraseBook, in a //switch

```
case 6: 
                    AppLibrary.cleanscreen();//Static method to erase the screen
                    System.out.println("What book do u wish to delete?");
                    String inventary = ghandi.generateInventory();//this makes the        //inventory to the user
                        if(inventary.equals("")){
                            System.out.println("No books available in the inventary");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(inventary);
                        }
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());//here i read from the //keyboard the number of book the user wants to delete
//Here the object libary is caled "ghandi"
                    ghandi.eraseBook(num);//here i use the method
                    System.out.println("Book erase, please display inventary again");
                   s.nextLine();
                    break;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `void` if you don't want to return anything (which I assume is the case here).

If you want to return the object you're in (so, the current library that you just deleted from), use the `this` keyword.

Comment: No, i want to return the object library named ghandi, to use it after the book is erased P:

Comment: @Pony: check my update. But still, you don't have to return the current library if you already have your Ghandi object..

Comment: :ooo ok thik that i get it Thankss!

Answer (score 0):

add a constructor Library(Book[] inventary, int booksquantity) and call it in the return method so.

```
public class Library {

 private Book[] inventary;
 private int     booksquantity;

 public Library(Book[] inventary, int booksquantity){
    this.inventary = inventary;
    this.booksquantity = booksquantity;
 }

 public Library eraseBook(int num){
    for(int i = 0; i<booksquantity ; i++){ 
       if((inventary[i] == inventary[num-1]) && (inventary[i+1] != null)){
           inventary[i+1]= inventary[i];
       } else if(inventary[i] == inventary[num-1]){
           inventary[i] = null;
       }
   } 
      return new Library(inventary, booksquantity);
 }  
}
```

if you just want to erase a book and not make the whole class immutable.

```
public class Library {

 private Book[] inventary;
 private int     booksquantity;

 public Library(Book[] inventary, int booksquantity){
    this.inventary = inventary;
    this.booksquantity = booksquantity;
 }

 public void eraseBook(int num){
    for(int i = 0; i<booksquantity ; i++){ 
       if((inventary[i] == inventary[num-1]) && (inventary[i+1] != null)){
           inventary[i+1]= inventary[i];
       } else if(inventary[i] == inventary[num-1]){
           inventary[i] = null;
       }
   } 
 }  
}
```

Comment: How would this work? You delete a book from a library and suddenly you have a whole new library? All you have to do is adjust the local array with books.

Comment: I think he wants Library to be immutable. Like how substring returns a string but does not modify the original string.

Comment: That doesn't quite sound like a library. This sentence "I want to make a method that erase an object book in the array inventary, but i dont how to declare the return value of the method." Makes it pretty clear he just want to reflecht the inventory change in the array.

Comment: But his method return type is Library. As such, it should return a Library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `void` if you do not want to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use void as the method signature:

```
public void eraseBook(int num){}
```

Or you could return null at the end of method, but that is not a good practice.